# How to change Adobe Stock Invitation card template text in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I licensed the template "Invitation card - black and gold vintage style" in Adobe Stock, and opened it in Adobe Illustrator.
I am trying to change:

- the text "Invitation"
- the text "Sample text here"
- the text "Place your text here"

View of the template at the start:

[image]

My attempt:

1. In Layers, activated the wanted object only to be edited, not locked
2. selecting *Type tool* and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, I got:

[image]

but double clicking does not allow to change the text.

Target: change "INVITATION" to "KUTSU", meaning invitation in Finnish.

AI version: latest
OS: Windows 11, latest

Comment: One should not assume that anything in a stock asset is editable.

Comment: The blue outline around the text means that it has been converted to outlines and is no longer editable text. You will probably need to retype it, and delete the existing text.

Answer (score 3):

The text has been converted to outlines.

All you can do is delete it and retype whatever you want.

You can't easily change what's existing - it's a collection of nodes and paths which *looks* like text, but it is **not** "live" text you can change.